# AWS Route 53 - Not Receiving NS Records

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

My domain was in different provider.

So I create record on AWS Route 53,
And find the NS records. So that, o copy and paste them to my provider's NS Records.

[image]

But after redirection, my A and CNAME records are not working.
I made NS lookup and It returned that; records are belong to AWS Route 53 but not working yet.

[image]

After that I've seen that,
My SOA Records are not belong to AWS. It still belongs to another provider:

[image]

So that,
I can not manage my DNS records by Route 53.
But NS records are shown as AWS.

Whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a TTL attached with each record and is managed by the service provider. So it is important to understand how you're testing the NS and other records value. I will recommend to use https://mxtoolbox.com/ which will ignore the multi levels of cache in the DNS lifecycle.

Once your NS servers are updated. You can setup any txt record to test that AWS Route53 is working for you. The best part is Route53 is super FAST and updates in seconds instead of days for some other providers. Then just go ahead and setup your A records & CNAME.

Comment: thats so weird. because It passed 16 hours until we redirect NS records. mxtoolbox.com says "Reported by ns1.vargonen.net on 2/8/2022 at 12:52:30 AM (UTC -6), just for you.".

Comment: @TCS Does that mean it is working correctly for you now?

Comment: no it doesnt. it looksup wrong NS even we enter AWS NS.

Comment: Can you confirm the TTL of your records in the old service